# How the path module handle path

Tags: nodes, views, path-aliases

I have two path one is "book/content/9(book_id)" render a View page
and another is "book/content/book_alias" (autopath)

Now view get a argument 9 and display a View Page but when "book/content/book_alias" is requested display a node rather than node in View Page
why this happen ? and how to solve this ?

Comment: Are you trying to override node path using views?

Comment: yes using "book/content/%"

Comment: So you need to change the path alias for book content type. You can do this in configuration.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive  Sorry clive the question is different i asked how to path module work ? for it two different path..... ""HOW TO REACT A PATH MODULE ON THAT"